# Complex synonym matching

Tags: regex, search, solr, lucene, synonym

I need to do some synonym matching with Solr.

For instance in Sweden streetnames usually have the form of `Foogatan` where gatan is name for street in english. This street name can be written out abbreviated like `Foog.` (kinda like you write `st.` for `street` in english)

I'm familiar with how `synonyms.txt` works but I don't know how to create a synonym that will check that it contains some letters before `gatan` or before `g.`.

I would need a synonym that would match `*g.` and `*gatan`.

I ended up doing this (seems to work as a rough draft for what I'm after)

```
public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {

    // See http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/

    if (!input.incrementToken()) return false;

    String string = charTermAttr.toString();

    boolean containsGatan = string.contains("gatan");
    boolean containsG = string.contains("g.");

    if (containsGatan) {

        string = string.replace("gatan", "g.");

        char[] newBuffer = string.toCharArray();

        charTermAttr.setEmpty();
        charTermAttr.copyBuffer(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.length);

        return true;
    }

    if (containsG) {

        string = string.replace("g.", "gatan");

        char[] newBuffer = string.toCharArray();

        charTermAttr.setEmpty();
        charTermAttr.copyBuffer(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.length);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also a similar problem I have is that you can write phone numbers in the form of `031-123456` and  `031123456`. When searching for a phone number like 031123456 it should **also** find 031-123456

How can I achieve this in Solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one you could write a custom `TokenFilter` and hook it up in your analyzers (it's not that hard, take a look at `org.apache.lucene.analysis.ASCIIFoldingFilter` for some simple example).

Second one could possibly be solved by using `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory`:
http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/CharFilterFactories

You would have to remove '-' character from numbers and index/search for numbers only.
Similar question:
[Solr PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory not replacing with specified pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524678/solr-patternreplacecharfilterfactory-not-replacing-with-specified-pattern)

Simple example removing gatan from end of each token:

```
public class Gatanizer extends TokenFilter {

    private final CharTermAttribute termAttribute = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    /**
     * Construct a token stream filtering the given input.
     */
    protected Gatanizer(TokenStream input) {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (input.incrementToken()) {

            final char[] buffer = termAttribute.buffer();
            final int length = termAttribute.length();

            String tokenString = new String(buffer, 0, length);
            tokenString = StringUtils.removeEnd(tokenString, "gatan");

            termAttribute.setEmpty();
            termAttribute.append(tokenString);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

and I've registered my `TokenFilter` to some Solr field:

```
    <fieldtype name="gatan" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="gatanizer.GatanizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

You'll also need some simple `GatanizerFactory` that will return your `Gatanizer`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the second one, the phone number will be in a string like "His phonenumber is 031-123456" so this whole string will be indexed (it's like a comment field where unstructured information can be written). Is it then still possible to use the `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory`? Or is it only possible to use if you know that the field is of type "phonenumber" ?

Comment: It should be possible to use it on any field, you would just have to prepare regexp so it does not break some other tokens in text.

You might also have some issues with `MaxBlockChars` buffer if your field contains a lot of text. Then you might have to go with custom tokenizer.

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail how to achieve first issue? I updated with some code on what I have tried... but it's unfortunately not working...

Comment: Ive implemented some simple filter that does almost what you need. It has one issue - it won't remove g. as . is removed by standard tokenizer. You'll need some more hacking in tokenizer for that. See updated response.